# Laravel 5.4 Field doesn't have a default value with no use of create

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, laravel-5.4, laravel-translatable

Very strange behavior with `save()`. I don't use method `create`. This is the creating new record code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required',
            'weight' => 'required|integer|max:99,min:-99',
            'color' => 'required|regex:/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/',
            'suspension' => 'required|integer|in:0,1'
        ]);        
        $status = new Status();
        $status->weight = $request->weight;
        $status->title = request('title');
       // dd($request->title);

        $status->color = $request->color;
        $status->suspension = $request->suspension;
        $status->description = $request->description;
        $status->save();
        $request->session()->flash('status','success');
        $request->session()->flash('msg',__('Status has benn created Successfully'));
        return redirect('/status');

    }
```

However, I have got the following message about the `title` field:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `statuses` (`weight`, `color`,
>   `suspension`) values (-9, #FFD700, 0))

So it is not an issue of `$fillable`!

I have the translation package [Laravel Translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable). Just when stop using it from `Status` model, it saves fine!

**However** I have another model which uses the same package with the same way but it could able to save new records successfully!

I could not able to figure out the root cause f this issue.

### Update

The only working solution till now, is to set `'strict' => false,` in the MySQL configuration. However, I still does not able to understand what's happening?!

Comment: What does the translate package do? From this behaviour it&#39;s probably that it tries to translate the title but failed and it returns null. Therefore the value of title becomes empty and failed to save.

Comment: Good idea. I checked out the other model that its save works and I found its title's table field accepts `null`. @k32y

Comment: I think the problem is, you have used `request('title')` but it should be `$request->get('title');`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay the `dd($request->title)` prints out the value of title field correctly.

Comment: ok @SaidbakR, but did you notice that you have used like this `$status->title = request('title');` so change it to `$status->title = $request->title;`

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If so then post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

did you notice that you have used like this `$status->title = request('title');` so change it to `$status->title = $request->title;`

Comment: The original implementation is using `$request->title`. I believe now its the translatable package issue